# Would this be a suitable place for asking about a home electrical installation problem?

Tags: discussion

I'm a homeowner with an electrical installation issue, and since the electricians that took a look at the problem left me in the dark, I'm turning to the Internet for advice (in hopes I find an engineer who actually *understands* what's going on).

Would this stack exchange be suitable for my question? It involves circuit breakers randomly tripping, weird (ghost?) voltages between circuits and finding methods for pinpointing the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I think the best place to ask these kind of questions is on the [Home Improvement stack](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), although there can be an overlap between this site and the electrical engineering stack for the particular subject you mention.

The Home Improvement stack is better aware of the electrical code constraints that apply to homes, and I'm pretty sure the answers will be better suited for the average handyman. There are regularily questions about electrical wiring there, that get very good answers.

On the other hand, the electrical engineering stack is more focused on electronic design / electrical theory, and your question does not really fit here. Besides, repair questions often get closed as off-topic.

Comment: I concur with @dim.  In addition, DIY.SE has got a fairly active [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/home-improvement), and you can trial your question there.